# How do I quit/close a lot of MATLAB instances after the execution of a script is finished through Batch script?

Tags: matlab, command-line, command

I execute a matlab script which call other Batch scripts and generate with that other matlab instances (as if i opened matlab multiple times) at the same time at the end stay a lot of opened matlab windows , how can i to kill all matlab.exe instances running on my system. after finishing the execution of my main script ?

Comment: [`close`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/close.html)?

Comment: `close all` maybe?

Comment: No the script opened multiple matlab windows as if i opened / clicked  matlab icon multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `quit` or `exit` to terminate *SAME* matlab instance. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quit.html
So, put these codewords at the end of the scripts so matlab instances close after scripts finish.

You cannot use matlab to terminate other running processes on your system. But you can run an external script - say some batch command that kills all matlab.exe instances running on your system. You do that by doing `system('scriptName')` in matlab, where `scriptName` is whatever you named this external bat script that kills the process.

To kill the process isn't a matlab question. One-liner solution can be found here:
https://superuser.com/questions/564878/killing-all-instance-of-a-specific-program-from-the-command-line

Solution for that script together with MATLAB code can be even found as a matlab question, coincidentally with exactly the "kill all instances" question:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/472-can-i-run-a-bat-file-with-matlab